# Why is my correlation matrix coming empty?

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\amgup\Downloads\Model_Wells\combined.csv", sep=',', usecols=['ACOUSTICIMPEDANCE1', 'CALI', 'DT','GR','NPHI','RHOB','LLD','PIGN','SP','VCL'], dtype='unicode')
cor=data.corr()
print(cor)
```

Comment: It's working now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably none of your columns are numeric. You have to typecast them to numeric values. That way you can calculate correlation.
Example:

```
data['CALI'] = data['CALI'].astype(np.float64)
```

Comment: Right, OP is using `dtype='unicode'`.